# java kafka api: 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' from calls to AdminClient

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Trying to do a simple 'enum topics' as such:

```
private static Collection<TopicListing> getTopicListing(boolean isInternal)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.put("client.id","java-admin-client");

    try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(properties)) {
      ListTopicsOptions options = new ListTopicsOptions();
      options.listInternal(isInternal);
      return client.listTopics(options).listings().get();
    }
}
```

kafka brokers are running on MSK (AWS managed kafka). The consumer has to run in a k8-pod for various security reasons. I've tried adding memory up to 1.5Gi (which seems crazy for a pod that does this one thing).

Error:

```
"level":"INFO","logger_name":"o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser","thread_name":"kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client","message":"App info kafka.admin.client for java-admin-client unregistered"}
"level":"INFO","logger_name":"o.a.k.c.a.internals.AdminMetadataManager","thread_name":"kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client","message":"[AdminClient clientId=java-admin-client] Metadata update failed","stack_trace":"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata\n"}
"level":"INFO","logger_name":"o.a.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient","thread_name":"kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client","message":"[AdminClient clientId=java-admin-client] Timed out 2 remaining operation(s) during close."}
"level":"INFO","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics","thread_name":"kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client","message":"Metrics scheduler closed"}
"level":"INFO","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics","thread_name":"kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client","message":"Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter"}
"level":"INFO","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics","thread_name":"kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client","message":"Metrics reporters closed"}

"level":"ERROR","logger_name":"o.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread","thread_name":"kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client",
"message":"Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-admin-client-thread | java-admin-client':",
"stack_trace":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)\
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1400)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1331)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"}
```

Comment: The place where an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs isn't necessarily the place that causes the problem. It's just the last drop in the bucket. That also means its difficult to diagnose and you probably should look into getting a heap dump to investigate what holds onto all the memory. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121941/how-to-get-a-heap-dump-from-kubernetes-k8s-pod

Comment: The JVM itself may be limited in size. It doesn't always use the size of the pod

Comment: This is essentially the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375592/java-heap-space-out-of-memory-error-kafka-broker-with-sasl-ssl